# Cufon rendering line breaks

Tags: javascript, cufon

I have been using cufon for the last year and a half and have never seen this...

Say I have:

```
<h2 class="my_font">This is some text</h2>    
<p class="my_font">This is some more text</p>
```

The text is rendered properly but the line break gets rendered as a new line, for example:

```
<h2 class="my_font"><cufon class="cufon cufon-canvas" alt=" " style="width: 5px; height: 16px; ">...</cufon</h2>

<cufon class="cufon cufon-canvas" alt=" " style="width: 5px; height: 16px; ">...</cufon>

<p class="my_font"><cufon class="cufon cufon-canvas" alt=" " style="width: 5px; height: 16px; ">...</cufon</p>
```

So I end up with a 16px gap between the h2 and p tags. The only thing I have been able to do to prevent it is, put everything on the same line or comment out the line break:

```
<h2 class="my_font">This is some text</h2><!--    
--><p class="my_font">This is some more text</p>
```

Also, I think it's important to mention that this happens anywhere cufon is used, it's not isolated to the html example above. Any idea what could be causing this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

What does your `Cufon.replace('');` code look like?

This can be caused by doing lazy replaces on large parent elements like this:

```
Cufon.replace('ul, div#foo');
```

Instead you should be more specific and target the specific elements inside the container, such as:

```
Cufon.replace('div#foo h2, div#foo span');
```

Perhaps that's not your issues but I've seen it happen before this way. Let me know.

Comment: Cufon.replace('.my_font'); - then I just apply the class wherever I need to use it.

Comment: Strange, that shouldn't cause a problem then. Out of interest does the problem persist if you do try just targeting the h2 and p using a parent container? so Cufon.replace('#container h2, #container p');